# How to shorten repetitive jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I am wondering how to shorten this code so it's not repeated. I tried an array with the IDs, but it didn't work.

Heres the code :

```
/* Autoplays the videos on open */

$('#modal-video1').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
    $(this).find('video')[0].play();
})

$('#modal-video2').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
    $(this).find('video')[0].play();
})

$('#modal-video3').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
    $(this).find('video')[0].play();
})

/* Stops and resets the videos on close */

$('#modal-video1').modal({
    show: false
}).on('hidden.bs.modal', function(){
    $(this).find('video')[0].pause();
    $(this).find('video')[0].load();
});

$('#modal-video2').modal({
    show: false
}).on('hidden.bs.modal', function(){
    $(this).find('video')[0].pause();
    $(this).find('video')[0].load();
});

$('#modal-video3').modal({
    show: false
}).on('hidden.bs.modal', function(){
    $(this).find('video')[0].pause();
    $(this).find('video')[0].load();
});
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can put your selectors in an array and use jQuery.each to iterate over the array and apply your  jQuery to each entry in the array

Comment: Another option would be to use a class instead of an id for your selector

Comment: Assuming you can control the structure of the HTML, the obvious solution is to add a common class for all of these, rather than unique IDs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a multiple selector - see [Multiple Selector in jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/) for more information. Your code will look like this:

```
$('#modal-video1, #modal-video2, #modal-video3').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
    $(this).find('video')[0].play();
});

$('#modal-video1, #modal-video2, #modal-video3').modal({
    show: false
}).on('hidden.bs.modal', function(){
    var video = $(this).find('video')[0];
    video.pause();
    video.load();
});
```

Comment: This is much improved over the original, but note that the selectors are still duplicated, as is `$(this).find('video')[0]` in the hidden.bs.modal handler.

Comment: thanks guys, i'd made a silly mistake and unnecessarily wrapped each ID. Problem solved, apologies for being such a novice!

Answer (score 1):

You can comma-separate selectors in jQuery. Also, you can chain your functions, and you can store the results of a query in a variable instead of repeating code:

```
$('#modal-video1, #modal-video2, #modal-video3').modal({
    show: false
})

/* Plays the video on open */
.on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
    $(this).find('video')[0].play();
})

/* Stops and resets the videos on close */
.on('hidden.bs.modal', function() {
    var video = $(this).find('video')[0];
    video.pause();
    video.load();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For the first part of code you can do as the following
bind would change the context of this

```js
$('#modal-video1').on('shown.bs.modal',play.bind(this))

$('#modal-video2').on('shown.bs.modal',play.bind(this))

$('#modal-video3').on('shown.bs.modal',play.bind(this))

function play(){
 $(this).find('video')[0].play();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I think you're missing the part where the video is loaded and paused!